# Counting failed commands when using `sem`

Tags: gnu-parallel

I want to run several shell scripts in parallel using `sem` and get the number of failed commands.  However, their exit codes are always zero:

```
sem bash -c 'exit 0'
echo $? # => 0
sem bash -c 'exit 1'
echo $? # => 0
sem --wait
echo $? # => 0
```

How can I get the count?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. `sem` does not communicate with the process and thus cannot get the exit value.

If you want that, use `parallel` instead.

```
$ parallel "bash -c 'exit '{}" ::: 0 1 2 3 4 0
$ echo $?
4
```

This works until 100. 101 indicates > 100 jobs failed.

If you have more failing jobs than this, use `--joblog` and count the failures in the column `Exitval`.